# Randomly distribute collections across cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Requirements:

- up to one billion of documents per chunk (single shard key)
- tens of thousands chunks(30k)
- queries are run only in chunk scope - filtered by shard key
- 3 indexes - single: hashed shard key, compound: shard key + _id, compound: shard key + 3 fields
- all access paths are write - insert, find and update, find and delete

What sharding strategy should I pick for MongoDb?

1. Mongo hash-based sharding with shard key (String)
2. Application level pseudo-sharding with each chunk going to its separate collection

Concerns about MongoDb:

- Indexes won't fit in memory for billion of documents
- All queries are write and Mongo is Master-Slave

Is option 1 a good idea?

With option 2, is it possible to randomly distribute collections across Mongo cluster?

Comment: Can I ask what you mean when you say "all queries are write" ?

Comment: @VinceBowdren we can assume not having any significant read traffic to Mongo - can't offload to replicas.